# Get the list of visible text from label

Tags: java, selenium

I am in the learning stage of selenium and trying to get values from the below html code. There are multiple labels and I want text values from all the labels
for example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label/div/div/span(@class='inline-label')])).gettext(); //result = British Airways
```

in the same way, ever label has a text value. is there a way that I get the text value from all different labels(the xpath is the same for all) through loop.
Expecting results as 
British Airways,
lufthansa Airways,
Jet Airways,
xyz...

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please include any required text (such as code) as text in your question, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You xpath has syntax errors, it should be `//label/div/div/span[contains(.,'xxxxx')]`.

If you want to get label element than contains "xxx" text use xpath below:

```
//label[./span[contains(.'xxxxx')]]
```

Update:

Because labels not visible you cannot use `getText()`, instead you use `textContent` attribute. To get all labels use `findElements`:

```
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.inline-label"));
labels.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.getAttribute("textContent")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try now you should get list of element and their text.

```
List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='inline-label']"));
  for(int i=0;i<listData.size();j++) {

    System.out.print(listData.get(i).getText());

    }
```

Let me know if you get any problem.